# Django: Update an object from form

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make my view to update an existing object, filling its attrs with form data.
I found the syntaxis for this:

```
Auxi.objects.filter(id=auxi).update(name='The new name', age=23, role='The new role')
```

(Assuming that `auxi` is the object id value that the view is receiving)

But the problem is that it will become too extensive for my object since it has 52 attrs and I just want to tell Django to replace **all** the values from my object with the data from form.

I tried:

```
form = AuxiForm(request.POST)
item = form.save(commit=False)
Auxi.objects.filter(id=auxi).update(form)
```

and also

```
Auxi.objects.filter(id=auxi).update(item)
```

But it's saying `update() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`.
Could someone help me please? Sorry if it's a duplicate post, I already tried to find it somewhere but I couldn't.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i update my instances:

```
obj, created = Auxi.objects.update_or_create(
    id=auxi,
    defaults={
        name='The new name', 
        age=23, 
        role='The new role'}
)
obj.save()
```